# Hover Material UI Icon and Text

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a React JS Project. I was making something like a breadcrumb where there is a text and an icon. I am using material UI icon.

```
          import UpdateIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Update";
          import styles from " myfile.module.css "

          <div className={styles.headItem}>
              <UpdateIcon
                className={classes.bread}
              />
              <h1
                className={styles.bread}
              >
               Bread Text
              </h1>
            </div>
```

Problem : I want to set the hover of this icon + text. But I have module file for normal html elements and material UI makestyles for materia UI items.

So I can't set the hover of whole. I tried setting the headItem class but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make some changes, the first one is that I prefer to import the css styles like this, because you can use the classes as regular strings

```
import "./styles.css";
```

Suppose that your styles.css have this class that is just applying the regular styles for your breadcrumb.

```
.head {
 text-decoration: underline;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Then you can reference this class in your file:

```
import React from "react";
import UpdateIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Update";
import "./styles.css";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
 bread: {
  "&:hover": {
   color: "green"
  }
 }
});

export default function App() {
 const classes = useStyles();
  return (
   <div className={`head ${classes.bread}`}>
    <UpdateIcon />
    <h1>Bread Text</h1>
   </div>
  );
 }
```

Notice that we're referencing the css class that we have on the styles.css as a string, and then we just add the material ui class variable by using string interpolation. I have this sandbox where you can see the result:

https://codesandbox.io/s/still-pine-0v2jw